# Form bound, but has nothing in cleaned_data

Tags: ajax, django, forms, post

I feel like this may be something simple that I am missing, however since the post data is coming from an AJAX call in my angular javascript I couldn't be too sure. In a nutshell, I get data from an AJAX call in request.body, which I have a function to handle it and turn it into a query dictionary to bind to my form. It has worked up until this point. The form is valid according to form.is_valid, and I can see the data is being posted, but it doesn't have anything in it's cleaned_data attribute.

```
def requestPost(request):
    querystring = urllib.urlencode(ast.literal_eval(request.body))
    postdata = QueryDict(query_string=querystring)

    return postdata

def send(request, thread_id):
    # """Send a message to the thread."""

    account = Account.objects.get(email=request.user.username)
    thread = Thread.objects.get(id=thread_id)

    if request.method == "POST":
        x = requestPost(request)
        form = NewChat(requestPost(request))

        if form.is_valid():
            cleaned_data = form.cleaned_data
            threadchat = ThreadChat.objects.create(text=cleaned_data['message'], account=account, thread=thread)

            broadcast(threadchat.id)

            context = {"threadchat": threadchat}
            return composeJsonResponse(200, "", context)
```

[image]

```
class NewChat(forms.Form):
    message = forms.Textarea()
```

Comment: What's the point of the requestPost function? Why don't you access request.POST directly?

Comment: since the post data is coming from angular as an AJAX call, the data is coming through in request's body attribute as a string. So I had to handle the string, and convert it into a QueryDict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forms.Textarea` is not a field, it is a widget. Your form has no actual fields in it, so `cleaned_data` is empty.

You should use `forms.CharField` in your form; if you need it to display as a textarea you can pass that as the widget argument:

```
class NewChat(forms.Form):
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea())
```

Comment: Awesome, it worked. Always bailin me out Daniel hah, thanks !